# Does JSoupParserBolt has an inbuilt implementation to utilise parsefilters.json file and the classes associated with it?

Tags: web-crawler, apache-storm, stormcrawler

I was looking into specific XPath data extraction using filter classes provided within storm crawler. I was wondering whether **JSoupParserBolt** utilises the classes associated around filter classes and files or we do have to override filter classes to extract the required data.
Also I was trying to understand how to use **indexer.md.filter** and **indexer.md.mapping** entries from **crawler_conf.yaml**, but due to limited documentation, the use is not clear to me.
Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSoupParserBolt calls the ParseFilters defined in *parsefilters.json*. [The one generated by the archetype](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/archetype/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/src/main/resources/parsefilters.json) gives a good example of what you can do with them. If you need to do some simple XPath extraction, you should be able to do that through configuration of the *com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.parse.filter.XPathFilter*. For instance,

```
"parse.title": [
        "//TITLE",
        "//META[@name=\"title\"]/@content"
     ]
```

will try to match two Xpath expressions and store whichever value if found in the metadata under the key *parse.title*.

You can of course implement custom ParseFilters, [this package](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/tree/master/core/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/parse/filter) contains various implementations that you can use as a source of inspiration.

As for the *indexer.md* configs, [see wiki](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/wiki/Configuration#indexing). Basically, the mapping allows you to rename the metadata keys

```
  indexer.md.mapping:
  - parse.title=title
  - parse.keywords=keywords
  - parse.description=description
  - domain=domain
```

in the example above the key 'parse.title' will be indexed as a field named 'title'. Only the metadata listed in mapping will be used for the indexing.

*indexer.md.filter* serves a different purpose. As explained in the [Javadoc](http://stormcrawler.net/docs/api/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/indexing/AbstractIndexerBolt.html#metadataFilterParamName), it is used to filter out (i.e skip indexing) a document which has the key+value in its metadata.